# RecyclerView in CoordinatorLayout scrolls to top on data change

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, state, android-coordinatorlayout

I have a RecyclerView inside Viewpager, inside of CoordinatorLayout, and I am trying to make endless scrolling with a top bar, that scrolls to the top and disappears, leaving only the RecyclerView. Scrolling works perfectly, but whenever I update data in the RecyclerView itself (even something as simple as `notifyItemChanged`), the RecyclerView scrolls to the top of itself. The AppBarLayout stays hidden, so only the state of the RecyclerView is changing. Here is the layout itself:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:background="@color/main_bg_color">


    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/main_bg_color"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayoutHeader"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <include
                android:id="@+id/includedLayout"
                layout="@layout/fragment_profile_before_viewpager" />

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:tabIconTint="@color/pink" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>


    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And the layout of viewpager item (just a recyclerview):

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/gridRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

When first data arrives, I call `notifyItemRangeInserted(0, newList.size())` on the adapter. When new data arrives, I call `notifyItemRangeInserted(oldListSize + 1, newList.size());`. However, nothing seems to help. I have tried:

- Setting `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` on the CoordinatorLayout, the ViewPager, and the RecyclerView itself.
- Setting `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` and `"false"` on the RecyclerView itself
- Using notifyDataSetChanged to update the layout
- Calling `recyclerview.stopScroll()` and `recyclerview.stopNestedScroll()`
- Saving the state of the recycler before data change using `onSaveInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState`
- The issue also persists if there is no ViewPager, and just a RecyclerView below the AppBarLayout.